# How to populate values second time when the profile page link is located

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I have populated values in JSP drop down using JSTL from the servlet which is an array list. I stored  it in the request attribute and I am successfully getting the values in the drop down during the  first page view (i.e) after login.

while making the second visit. I can't find it the values in the drop down. I traced that it again expects the request attribute from the same servlet. Also, I didn't want to store the values in the session. As this approach may combat with the performance. Also I wish to avoid the scriptlet coding. Hence I expect your valuable suggestions or approach for my problem.

Thank you.

**SERVLET-LINK**

```
                http://XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/App/Login
```

**SERVLET**

```
      hmap = getUserProfile(con, request, session);
      System.out.println("Requested Result---> " + hmap);
      request.setAttribute("accessConnect", con);
      request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp").forward(request, response); 
      logger.info("User Login Successful=");
```

**JSTL**

```
     <strong>City</strong>: <select id="city" name="city">
     <option value="sCity">Select City</option>

     <c:forEach var="cit" items="${RESULT1}">
            <option> <c:out value="${cit}"/> </option>
     </c:forEach>
```

**HYPERLINK CLICKED FOR PROFILE PAGE**

```
     http://XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/App/home.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found out the answer the servlet should be mapped in the web.xml and the do get Method should be called. Finally the drop down list too working now